# Multiple DropDownLists with the same name (inside foreach statement)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I'm having trouble when loading several DropDownLists that have the same name. I attach my code here:

**View:**

```
@{
   int i = 1

    foreach (var queue in Model.Queues)
    {
            using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeQueueState", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                List<SelectListItem> sli = ViewBag.states[i - 1];
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("state", sli)</div>
            }
     }
    i++
}
```

There's more code inside the view that I didn't show.

In my controller I simply change the state of the corresponding queue and load `ViewBag.states` with the List of `SelectedListItem` which contains the List of states with the correct state as 'Selected' for each queue.

The problem is that when the View is loaded, all the `DropDownLists` are loaded with the last modified state. For instance, if I changed the 5th queue from 'Open' to 'Closed' then all the `DropDownLists` appears with the '`Closed`' option selected (although in the DB the changes are applied correctly).

I think the problem is due to the binding that MVC does between the `DropDownList` name and the `SelectListItem` associated, but I can't change the DDL name to `"state" + @i`, because state is bound to the argument received in the '`ChangeQueueState`' method of my Controller.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the EditorFor helper was designed for cases like this. You'll need one editor template for what ever "Model" repersents, and inside of that you would use EditorFor again to repersent each "Queues". The naming convention to get the model binder to work is "Queues[#].state" where # is the index in the list. It complicates things when your view shows one model and the form you're trying to post to another action accepts a different type of model because the naming convention will be off (as you're seeing)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use different name for each drop down list. Assuming that each queue has an different ID, so try to use this code instead:

```
<div>@Html.DropDownList("state" + queue.ID, sli)</div>
```

Of course you need to distinguish which is which in the collection.
I do this quite often, wish it works for u.